# Trying to pass a variable between two deployment job, I cannot use $(Environment.ResourceName), it only works if the resource name is hardcoded

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to pass a variable in an Azure deployment between two jobs, (deployments).
[According to the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables), as I use `runOnce` and `resourceType` I need to pass the resource-name in the `variable:` tag.

The resource name is an environment variable, `$(Environment.ResourceName)`

```yaml
stages:
- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: A
...
          steps:
          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OutputVar;isOutput=true]$myVar"
            env:
              myVar: 'Hello World'
            name: printvar

  - deployment: B
...
  variables:
    Variable1: $[ dependencies.A.Outputs.['Deploy_$(Environment.ResourceName).printVar.OutputVar'] ]
    Variable2: $[ dependencies.A.Outputs.['Deploy_MyResourceName.printVar.OutputVar'] ]

...
```

But when I run the code above the `Variable1` is not set but `Variable2` is properly set.

So, the reason `Variable1` is not set is because `$(Environment.ResourceName)` is not expended.

I have also tried to output the value of `$(Environment.ResourceName)` and that value is properly set to `MyResourceName`, (in my example above).

How can I pass $(Environment.ResourceName) without hardcoding the value in the script?

Comment: What do you mean `Environment.ResourceName` is an environment variable? Where is that variable being defined? Pipeline variables are defined as environment variables, but environment variables are not automatically imported as pipeline variables.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, `environment.resourceName` is a deployment variable. That value cannot be used when getting `variables:` but it is required, (in some cases), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-deployment-environment?view=azure-pipelines#environment-name-resourcename-resourceid-resourcetype-tags. It can be hardcoded in `variables`, but I would like to use the environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, you need to use the nested variable: `$[ dependencies.A.Outputs.['Deploy_$(Environment.ResourceName).printVar.OutputVar'] ]` to get the output value in previous job.

I am afraid that the nested variable is not supported in Azure DevOps. So the variable: **$(Environment.ResourceName)** is not able to expand as expected.

> How can I pass $(Environment.ResourceName) without hardcoding the value in the script?

I suggest that you can change to use Parameters to pass the value to the variable.

Then you can use the format: `$[ dependencies.A.outputs['${{parameters.name}}.setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]`

For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: MyResourceName
    type: string
    default: MyResourceName

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


stages:
- stage: Stage
  jobs:
  - deployment: A
...
          steps:
          - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=OutputVar;isOutput=true]$myVar"
            env:
              myVar: 'Hello World'
            name: printvar

  - deployment: B
...
  variables:
    Variable1: $[ dependencies.A.Outputs.['Deploy_${{parameters.MyResourceName}}.printVar.OutputVar'] ]
    Variable2: $[ dependencies.A.Outputs.['Deploy_MyResourceName.printVar.OutputVar'] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work as a solution for now, ideally I would have set the default value to `default: $(Environment.ResourceName)` but it is not known when the release is created.

Comment: I can full understand know your requirement. But the value also needs to be set at compile time. $(Environment.ResourceName) will expand at runtime. I am afraid that it can not achieved.

Comment: If you don't want to hardcode the value, parameter is the best method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Environment.ResourceName` directly in job B. It is a deployment job variable and is scoped to a specific deployment job, so there isn't such a variable named `Environment.ResourceName` in job B. Based on my knowledge, currently only the hard-coded way to map variables is supported.